# how can i display nested loops using python

Tags: python, selenium, loops, web-scraping, nested-loops

I am a beginner in python and I have started with web scraping, I want to extract data from a tourist site I need the names of the hotels, the arrangements available in each hotel and the price but I got stuck in the list of arrangements, each hotel can have several arrangements but it doesn't work and I don't know why.
I put at your disposal my code and the output provided if any of you can help me and thank you in advance.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

PATH = "C:\\Users\\marketing2\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://tn.tunisiebooking.com/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# write script //Your Script Seems fine
script = "document.getElementById('ville_des').value ='Sousse';document.getElementById('depart').value ='05/08/2021';document.getElementById('checkin').value ='05/08/2021';document.getElementById('select_ch').value = '1';"

# Execute script
driver.execute_script(script)

# click bouton search
btn_rechercher = driver.find_element_by_id('boutonr')
btn_rechercher.click()
sleep(10)

# click bouton details
btn_plus = driver.find_element_by_id('plus_res')
btn_plus.click()
sleep(10)

#getting the hotel names and by xpath in a loop
hotels=[]
pensions=[]
for v in range(1, 5):
        hotel = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[' + str(v) + ']/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span/a/h3').get_attribute('innerHTML')
        for j in range (1,3):
            pension= driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[' + str(j) + ']/u').get_attribute('innerHTML')
        pensions.append((pension))
        hotels.append((hotel,pensions))
        

print(hotels)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import json
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select


# create path and start webdriver
PATH = "/mnt/sdc/Work/scripts/Test/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

# first get website
driver.get('https://tn.tunisiebooking.com/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# params to select
params = {
    'destination': 'Sousse',
    'date_from': '05/08/2021',
    'date_to': '05/08/2021',
    'bedroom': '1'
}

# select destination
destination_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ville_des'))
destination_select.select_by_value(params['destination'])

# select bedroom
bedroom_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('select_ch'))
bedroom_select.select_by_value(params['bedroom'])

# select dates
script = f"document.getElementById('depart').value ='{params['date_from']}';"
script += f"document.getElementById('checkin').value ='{params['date_to']}';"
driver.execute_script(script)

# submit form
form = driver.find_element_by_id('hotel_recherch_moteur')
form.submit()
sleep(5)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# get list of all hotels
hotels_list = []
hotels_objects = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '//div[contains(@class, "enveloppe_produit")]'
)
for hotel_obj in hotels_objects:
    # get price object
    price_object = hotel_obj.find_element_by_xpath(
        './/div[@class="monaieprix"]'
    )
    price_value = price_object.find_element_by_xpath(
        './/div[1]'
    ).text.replace('\n', '')

    # get title data
    title_data = hotel_obj.find_element_by_xpath(
        './/span[contains(@class, "tittre_hotel")]'
    )

    # get arrangements
    arrangements_obj = hotel_obj.find_elements_by_xpath(
        './/div[contains(@class, "angle")]//u'
    )
    arrangements = [ao.text for ao in arrangements_obj]

    # create new object
    hotels_list.append({
        'name': title_data.find_element_by_xpath('.//a//h3').text,
        'arrangements': arrangements,
        'price': f'{price_value}'
    })

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
for hotel in hotels_list:
    print(json.dumps(hotel, indent=4))
```

```
{
    "name": "El Mouradi Palace",
    "arrangements": [
        "Petit dejeuner",
        "Demi pension plus",
        "All inclusive soft"
    ],
    "price": "67"
}
{
    "name": "KANTA",
    "arrangements": [
        "Petit dejeuner",
        "Demi pension",
        "All inclusive soft"
    ],
    "price": "43"
}
...
```

If I help you - please mark answer as correct

Comment: thank you for response i will mark it as correct anyways because you helped me a lot, but i want to ask you how can i show the arragements : all in soft , demi pension .. of every hotel this is the major probleme and thank you in advance

Comment: @HiFAR can you show me, what info do you want, cause i can't find that?

Comment: I added an image in the question section, hope this clarifies the situation

Answer (score 1):

You should find the required elements within the `hotels` variable by their `tag_name` or `xpath`.

Try the below code.

```
hotels = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@id,'produit_affair_')]")
hotel_list = []
for hotel in hotels:
    name = hotel.find_element_by_tag_name("h3").text
    prize = hotel.find_element_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@id,'prixtotal_')]").text
    hotel_list.append((name,prize))
print(hotel_list)
```

And the output:

```
[('El Mouradi Palace', '56'), ('KANTA', '56'), ('Occidental Sousse Marhaba', '56'), ('Sindbad Center GAS', '56'), ('Sousse palace', '56'), ('Tui Blue Scheherazade', '56'), ('Golf Residence GAS', '56'), ('Iberostar Kantaoui Bay', '56'), ('Iberostar Diar el Andalous', '56'), ('Riadh Palms', '56'), ('Seabel AlHambra Beach Golf & Spa', '56'), ('Sousse City & Beach Hotel', '56'), ('Thalassa Sousse', '56'), ('Marhaba Palace', '56'), ('Palmyra Aqua Park ex soviva', '56'), ('Houria Palace', '56'), ('Cosmos Tergui Club', '56'), ('Marhaba Beach', '56'), ('Marhaba Club', '56'), ('Sousse Pearl Marriott Resort & Spa', '56')]
```